# maven "Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory" error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I created a java project in eclipse. The project location is /home/vikas/code/primeNumberWorkSpace/primeNumber.
I linked the source and pom files from other locations (/home/vikas/code/primNumber/src/ and /home/vikas/code/primeNumber/pom.xml)
When i issue 'clean install' command from the eclipse, it gives the following error,

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
>   is no POM in this directory
>   (/home/vikas/code/primeNumberWorkSpace/primeNumber). Please verify you
>   invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

How to resolve this.

the pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>main.java.com.simpragma.primenumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>prime-number</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>

    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is the same command is working from terminal?

Comment: from terminal i am getting different set of errors.


`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project prime-number: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/vikas/code/primeNumber/src/main/java/com/simpragma/primenumber/PrimeNum.java:[6,10] operator <= cannot be applied to java.lang.Integer,int
[ERROR] `

maven version installed in the machine is 3.0.4

Comment: What does 'linked from other locations..' this mean?

Comment: As stated earlier my pom.xml and source files are in different location. To link them i did the following in eclipse,
right click on project name -->New-->File-->Advanced>>--->Link to file in the file System
And selected the file to be linked (pom.xml) from the given file browser.

Comment: Don't link anything. Download the M2E plugin. Then Import existing Maven Project. Everything will work after that. Creating a project that is in a different location than the real project is asking for problems.

Answer (score 1):

You might have tried setting the AutoRun registry key for Command Processor to change where cmd.exe has its starting location...

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

Check this value, as a CD in this autorun will change the default location of all cmd.exe that are run on the system.  Which is wonderful, but it apparently breaks something in maven workflow.

Deleted my AutoRun value and this issue went away for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue with maven projects within MuleSoft Anypoint Studio 6.4.4, which is based on Eclipse 4.5.2. By removing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun value the issue went away.

Thanks for your answer Dave Horner.